# Can you use Permanency on Mythic Spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, mythic-adventures

Recently discovered *[Mythic Enlarge Person](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicSpells/enlargePerson.html)*, and got excited for the idea of boosting my Mythic-powered Monk's unarmed damage.
Of course, mythic spellcasters are not exactly common entities, but presuming one can be found (as none of the party members are actually spellcasters) I'd love to have this effect made "permanent".

As *[Permanency](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/permanency.html)* doesn't explicitly call out the Mythic version of the spell, some members of the group argue against this being possible, but we couldn't find anything definitive.

**Question Time::**
Can *Mythic Enlarge Person* be made "permanent" with the *Permanency* spell, and if so what are the requirements in relation to the standard requirements for *Enlarge Person*?

If it doesn't apply to the mythic version of the spell, would it still apply to the base version once the mythic spell expires? (*And in this case maintain a single size category increase)*

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88223/do-the-base-mythic-spells-get-applied-to-greater-versions-of-the-spell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That depends

Mythic and non-mythic spells are considered different spells in the rules, as explained on my [other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88223/do-the-base-mythic-spells-get-applied-to-greater-versions-of-the-spell) on this same subject. This means that Fireball and Mythic Fireball are different spells, with the only similarity being that Mythic Fireball is a mythic improvement of the regular Fireball.

That said, you could come to this conclusion by reading the [Permanency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency) spell as well.

For instance, it lists [Magic Fang](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/) (2,500 gp) and Greater Magic Fang (7,500 gp), which are two different spells, one being a direct upgrade of the other, or a *variant*, which are spells with lesser and greater versions (magic fang, magic weapon, restoration, etc), or spells with numbers on it (summon monster, cure wounds, beast shape, etc).

Then, down the list, we see [Invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility) (5,000 gp), but no signs of Greater Invisibility, or Mass Invisibility. Meaning that these two other spells cannot be made permanent.

However, this is ultimately a GM decision, as the spell clearly leaves an option for GMs to add more spells to this list:

> The GM may allow other spells to be made permanent.

Personally, I would first check what Legendary Games (3rd party) did for Mythic Permanency on their [Mythic Spell Compendium](http://www.makeyourgamelegendary.com/products-page/all-products/mythic-spell-compendium/) and go from there. At a minimum, I would require the player to buy the Mythic version of Permanency simply to be able to make mythic spells permanent, because it doesn't make sense to use regular Permanency on mythic spells.

Comment: *Mythic Permanency* looks to be a bonus to how permanent the effects of the spell are, and makes no mention of use on mythic spell effects. The point about the list in *Permanency's* description is likely the greatest indicator that by RAW this isn't possible.

Comment: @royalmurder That is good to know. Since I don't own a copy of that book and the contents are not public, I simply pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @royalmurder  Having access to the book would be nice. I am in the same boat until I am willing to get that content or it becomes free.

Comment: @Fering likewise! *Mythic Permanency* is actually available (albeit hard to read on a mobile device) from Legendary Games' website ( http://www.makeyourgamelegendary.com/mythic-permanency/ )

Comment: @royalmurder Whoever decided that teak was a good colour for font on a white background fails

Comment: Oh, I failed my perception check when checking that exact same page.

Answer (score 1):

No.

My reasoning for this comes from two places. First is an [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/88224/23058) to a question about if the mythic base version of a spell would also apply to the non-mythic greater base spell, and the mythic spell is its own special spell.
Second is how [counterspells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Counterspells) work, by allowing a regular fireball to counter a empowered fireball. This means the spell is the same, and the metamagic is just an added effect which other effects ignore when interacting with them (usually, heighten spell is special). This leads me to believing that metamagic feats are basically wrappers around a spell that allow it to work better or function in a way you desire.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that, could you expand a little?

Comment: @royalmurder Ive expanded the answer to hopefully provide greater insight.

Comment: So by following the reasoning that *Permanency* wouldn't apply to a heightened spell, it would also not apply to mythic spells. Would it then simply apply to the base spell, instead? (I will add this to the question also.)

Comment: @royalmurder http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic Resilient: Any spell you cast as a mythic spell can also be cast in a resilient form that is harder to dispel or counterspell. Expend one additional use of mythic power; any check attempted in order to dispel the spell then takes a -4 penalty, and the spell can’t be countered unless the opposing caster also expends a use of mythic power to overcome your spell’s resilience (in which case the normal rules for counterspelling apply).